# CSS - Headers with border are not centered

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a problem that I simply cannot figure out. My headers have border on left side and some padding on the left. CSS (SASS) is defined like this:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
border-left: 2px solid $brand-light;
padding-left: 9px;
}
```

The thing is the text looks like it has padding on bottom (which is not true). If i extend padding on top it adds the padding which sort of makes it look centered but it is not what I want. I just want the border to be even with the text without adding any additional padding.

[image: See image here]

I have tried setting negative value on `padding-bottom` but that does not do anything. When I check out the element with chrome inspector, I also see this:

```
display: block;
font-size: 2em;
-webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
```

Comment: Try to add JSFiddle example and check `line height` value.

Comment: It looks good to me with the specs you mentioned so far. https://jsfiddle.net/efh5zeba/7/

Comment: hey guys thanks for quick answer. unfortunately its part of internal company project and html is created dynamically. will try the line height thing. i also havent tried other browsers to see if thats it

Answer (score 0):

Line-height seems to solve your problem. Matching it with the font-size (or less, depending what your flavor is) makes it the same height:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-family: 'Arial';
border-left: 4px solid red;
padding-left: 9px;
box-sizing: border-box;
line-height: 22px;
font-size: 24px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/adamk22/pen/NxZGNM